# jQuery issue with removing lines from block of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got the following line of strings:

```
aaaaaaaa1
bbbbbbbb2
cccccccc3
dddddddd4
```

And this is my field:

```
<textarea id="myLinesField"></textarea>
```

using jQuery, Having said that I am able to choose and remove any line (in any order), I am trying to remove specific lines from my lines say second line to have the exact result like the following:

```
aaaaaaaa1
cccccccc3
dddddddd4
```

This is my code:

```
var value = $('#myLinesField').val();
var newVal = recipientValue.replace(stringLineToBeRemoved,'');
var finalResults = newVal.replace("\n", "");
$('#myLinesField').val(finalResults);
```

But I get something like this in some cases (not always):

```
aaaaaaaa1cccccccc3

dddddddd4
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: Also update your HTML mark up here

Comment: Why do you remove all "\n"? And where does `stringLineToBeRemoved` come from? (is it possible it has some whitespace at the beginning or end?)

Comment: I can pass the line value to be removed based on that value from other field. I need to remove all the empty lines

Comment: try `var finalResults = newVal.replace(/(\r|\n)+/, "\n");` for removing blank lines. It replaces all strings of `\r` or `\n` with a single `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try this out:

**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/SpnrN/**

## JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
        var value = $('#myLinesField').val();
        var newVal = value.replace($("#strToRemove").val(), '');
        var finalResults = newVal.replace("\n", "");
        $('#myLinesField').val(finalResults);
    });
});
```

## Html:

```
<textarea id="myLinesField" style="height:100px;width:100px;">aaaaaaaa1 bbbbbbbb2 cccccccc3 dddddddd4</textarea>
<br/>
<br/>Please enter the string to remove :
<input type="text" id="strToRemove"></input>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`var finalResults = newVal.replace("\n", "");`

to

`var finalResults = newVal.replace("\n", "\r");`

A `carriage return` will ensure that the line that's attached itself to the previous line starts on the next (its own) line

Comment: This does not remove the empty lines!

Comment: It only removes a line and leave it empty as a empty line. I want that empty line to be removed as well mate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var stringLineToBeRemoved = "bbbbbbbb2";
    var foundin = $('textarea:contains("'+stringLineToBeRemoved+'")');
    if(foundin)
    {
        var value = $('#myLinesField').val();
        var newVal = value.replace(stringLineToBeRemoved,'');
        var finalResults = newVal.replace("\n", "");
        $('#myLinesField').val(finalResults);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method (see fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/29evM/):

```
var removeStr = function (str, index) {
    var parts = str.replace(/$(\s)*/gm, "\n").split("\n");
    parts.splice(index, 1);
    return parts.join("\n");
};
```

If your textarea is:

```
<textarea id="myLinesField">aaaaaaaa1
bbbbbbbb2

cccccccc3
dddddddd4</textarea>
```

Then:

```
var recipientValue = $('#myLinesField').val();
var finalResults = removeStr(recipientValue, 1);  // removes the 2nd line (non-empty line)
```

Will yield:

```
aaaaaaaa1
cccccccc3
dddddddd4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regexp

```
var stringLineToBeRemoved = 'cccccccc3';

var value = $('#myLinesField').val();
var regex =  new RegExp(stringLineToBeRemoved + '(\r\n|\n|\r)', 'm');
$('#myLinesField').val(value.replace(regex,''));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tg2yV/)